# Can I transform a EER Diagram in MySQL into a Microsoft Access Database?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have made a EER Diagram in MySQL Workbench 6.2, Simply used this as it's a nice free tool. The database will be (and sadly has to be) a Microsoft Access Database.

Is there a way I can send this EER to MS Access so it makes all of my tables, datatypes and relationships automatically?

I know there is a forward engineer tool but this is seemingly for sending to an existing SQL database on a server.

Answer (score 0):

The generated EER diagram is a complete own format. MS Access wouldn't know how to handle that. What you could do is to export the model to an SQL file and use some tool that can import MySQL SQL code into MS Access (though I know none as I never had the need).